# UIScrollView draw ruler using drawRect

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, core-graphics, drawrect

I am trying to draw a ruler on top of UIScrollView. The way I do it is by adding a custom view called RulerView. I add this rulerView to superview of scrollView setting its frame to be same as frame of scrollView. I then do custom drawing to draw lines as scrollView scrolls. But the drawing is not smooth, it stutters as I scroll and the end or begin line suddenly appears/disappears. What's wrong in my drawRect?

```
class RulerView: UIView {

   public var contentOffset = CGFloat(0) {
      didSet {
         self.setNeedsDisplay()
      }
   }

   public var contentSize = CGFloat(0)

   let smallLineHeight = CGFloat(4)
   let bigLineHeight = CGFloat(10)


  override open func layoutSubviews() {   
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear     
  }

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
 
     UIColor.white.set()
     let contentWidth = max(rect.width, contentSize)
     let lineGap:CGFloat = 5
    
     let totalNumberOfLines = Int(contentWidth/lineGap)
    
     let startIndex = Int(contentOffset/lineGap)
     let endIndex = Int((contentOffset + rect.width)/lineGap)
     let beginOffset = contentOffset - CGFloat(startIndex)*lineGap
    
     if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        for i in startIndex...endIndex {
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: beginOffset + CGFloat(i - startIndex)*lineGap , y:0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: beginOffset + CGFloat(i - startIndex)*lineGap, y: i % 5 == 0 ? bigLineHeight : smallLineHeight))
            path.lineWidth = 0.5
            path.stroke()

            
        }
    }
    
}
```

And in the scrollview delegate, I set this:

```
  //MARK:- UIScrollViewDelegate

public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    
    rulerView.contentSize = scrollView.contentSize.width
    rulerView.contentOffset = offset
}
```

Comment: Is your ruler view inside or outside of your scroll view?

Comment: It's outside UIScrollView along with texts on the big line marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect)` is very "heavy." I think you'll get much better performance by using a shape layer for your "tick marks" and letting `UIKit` handle the drawing.

---

**Edit** - *as per comments*

Added numbering to the tick marks using `CATextLayer` as sublayers.

Here's a sample `RulerView` (using your tick mark dimensions and spacing):

```
class RulerView: UIView {

    public var contentOffset: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.bounds.origin.x = contentOffset
        }
    }
    public var contentSize = CGFloat(0) {
        didSet {
            updateRuler()
        }
    }
    
    let smallLineHeight: CGFloat = 4
    let bigLineHeight: CGFloat = 10
    let lineGap:CGFloat = 5
    
    // numbers under the tick marks
    //  with 12-pt system font .light
    //  40-pt width will fit up to 5 digits
    let numbersWidth: CGFloat = 40
    let numbersFontSize: CGFloat = 12

    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        shapeLayer = self.layer as? CAShapeLayer
        // these properties don't change
        backgroundColor = .clear
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.5
        shapeLayer.masksToBounds = true
    }
    func updateRuler() -> Void {
        // size is set by .fontSize, so ofSize here is ignored
        let numbersFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 1, weight: .light)
        let pth = UIBezierPath()
        var x: CGFloat = 0
        var i = 0
        while x < contentSize {
            pth.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0))
            pth.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: i % 5 == 0 ? bigLineHeight : smallLineHeight))
            
            // number every 10 ticks - change as desired
            if i % 10 == 0 {
                let layer = CATextLayer()
                
                layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
                layer.font = numbersFont
                layer.fontSize = numbersFontSize
                layer.alignmentMode = .center
                layer.foregroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

                // if we want to number by tick count
                layer.string = "\(i)"
                
                // if we want to number by point count
                //layer.string = "\(i * Int(lineGap))"
                
                layer.frame = CGRect(x: x - (numbersWidth * 0.5), y: bigLineHeight, width: numbersWidth, height: numbersFontSize)
                
                shapeLayer.addSublayer(layer)
            }
            
            x += lineGap
            i += 1
        }
        shapeLayer.path = pth.cgPath

    }
}
```

and here's a sample controller class to demonstrate:

```
class RulerViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var rulerView: RulerView = RulerView()
    var scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        
        [scrollView, rulerView].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // sample scroll content will be a horizontal stack view
        //  with 30 labels
        //  spaced 20-pts apart
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.spacing = 20
        
        for i in 1...30 {
            let v = UILabel()
            v.textAlignment = .center
            v.backgroundColor = .yellow
            v.text = "Label \(i)"
            stack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }
        
        scrollView.addSubview(stack)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // scroll view 20-pts Top / Leading / Trailing
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            // scroll view Height: 60-pts
            scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
            
            // stack view 20-pts Top, 0-pts Leading / Trailing / Bottom (to scroll view's content layout guide)
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // ruler view 4-pts from scroll view Bottom
            rulerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            rulerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            // ruler view 0-pts from scroll view Leading / Trailing (equal width and horizontal position of scroll view)
            rulerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            // ruler view Height: 24-pts (make sure it's enough to accomodate ruler view's bigLineHeight plus numbering height)
            rulerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24.0),

        ])
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
        // so we can see the sroll view frame
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        // if we want to see the rulerView's frame
        //rulerView.backgroundColor = .brown
        
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // this is when we know the scroll view's content size
        rulerView.contentSize = scrollView.contentSize.width
    }
    public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // update rulerView's x-offset
        rulerView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x
    }
    
}
```

Output:

[image]

the tick marks (and numbers) will, of course, scroll left-right synched with the scroll view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also need to put text on ruler markings like 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,...I thought drawRect would allow me to do that as well. Your approach is not using drawRect. How do i extend it to put text on the marks? I see you put labels in a stackview. I would want them below the markings however.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - when asking for help, it's a good idea to post your ***complete*** question, rather than little bits and pieces. I edited my answer with *one* way of doing that. There are, of course, multiple approaches, but without knowing what you're really trying to do, I have no way of knowing if this would be suitable for your end goal.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - If *"the scrolling is super slow now"* then you are doing something else that you haven't revealed here.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - here's a link to a non-edited screen recording: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bwhIsO3g_Ta37Qf__zxK2iB7bA__B89-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's working now, i was setting both contentSize and contentOffset in scrollViewDidScroll. Repeated setting of contentSize was an issue.

Comment: This answer uses CAShapeLayer whose frame is essentially the content width of UIScrollView. As we scroll, you just update the bounds origin of the shape layer (which is essentially what UIScrollView does internally I guess). My question is whether UIKit only draws the necessary portion that is visible on the screen at runtime we scroll, or it stores the full view that backs the layer in memory? Just trying to understand the basics here.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - as I understand it, UIKit decides which parts of the layer(s) need to be drawn. For any more in-depth detail, I'd suggest running some profiling, or consulting an Apple UIKit engineer.

Comment: I was trying to extend your solution by zooming the CAShapeLayer as the scrollView zooms. Would need to increase or decrease the markings as well as gap between the marks as the scroll view zooms. Looks like it's not very flexible when you have CAShapeLayer. Need to implement custom drawing which is light weight.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - This sounds like it should be posted as a new question, as you need to clarify what you want to happen. Do you want only the gap between ticks to change? Do you want the frequency of the number labels to change? Do you want the tick values to change? And so on... Definitely beyond the scope of this (your original) question.

Comment: Do you do private consulting, willing to pay and get the full guidance on the UI side of project.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - yes, I (sometimes) do private consulting. I'd suggest creating a Private repo on GitHub and invite me as a Collaborator (my GitHub ID is also DonMag). Use the ReadMe for detailed descriptions of what you need help with.

Comment: Ok I will make a private github repo just for the UI part of project and invite you

Comment: Ok I sent you invite on Github. Please check.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - I'll use the "issues" section of that GitHub repo to communicate further.